# Numberformat Exception

Tags: java

i am trying to convert 2's complement binary number (in any bit) to decimal and i have given a numberformatexception.I am new at java. I tried hard to find what is the reason for that but i couldnt find it. Is there anyone who can say to me what is the problem of this code blog??

...

```
public static int decimal(String a){

        if((a.charAt(0)) == '1'){

        int length= a.length();
        String sum="";
        for (int i=0; i<=length; i++){
            int b=0;
            char result = a.charAt(b);
            b++;
            if(result == 0){
                result=1;
            }else{
                result=0;
            }
            sum= sum + result;
        }
        int num= Integer.parseInt(sum, 2);
        num= num+1;
        num*= -1;
        return num;
        }else{
            int decimalInt = Integer.parseInt(a, 2);
            return decimalInt;
        }   
    }
```

...

here is the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "         "
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:481)
    at BinaryToInstruction.decimal(BinaryToInstruction.java:193)
    at BinaryToInstruction.main(BinaryToInstruction.java:83)
```

Comment: what is at (BinaryToInstruction.java:193)??

Comment: Maybe you are doing this as a learning exercise, but are you aware of `Integer.parseInt(String str, int radix)`? It does what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I tried this but it worked just when the binary number is 16-bit. am I wrong ?? i tried it many times but it failed. Finally i decided to write my own code :)

Comment: What do you mean by 'the binary number is 16-bit'? It will work with any string comprised of '1' and '0' characters.

Comment: for example ; 0101 is 4-bit and 0101010101010101 is 16-bit

Comment: `System.out.println(Integer.parseInt("0101", 2));` prints 5 for me. Does it not for you?

Comment: but i am talking about 2's complement so if you try it for negative binary it doesnt work

Answer (score 4):

The problem is here :

```
if(result == 0){
       result=1;
 }else{
       result=0;
  }
```

result is a `char`, not an `int`. While this compiles (because a `char` can handle an int value from 0 to 65535), I think you wanna do :

```
if(result == '0'){
     result='1';
 }else{
     result='0';
 }
```

---

Note that you initialize `b` at 0 **in** the loop and so you'll only take the first `char` in your original String and swap it each time. Note that using a `StringBuilder` is better.

```
StringBuilder sum= new StringBuilder();
for (int i=0; i< a.length(); i++){
    char result = a.charAt(i);
    if(result == '0'){
        result='1';
    }else{
        result='0';
    }
    sum.append(result);
}
int num= Integer.parseInt(sum.toString(), 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the stack trace it looks as if you are passing only white space. This might be your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not a program for university classes you should use build in

```
Integer.parseInt(String str, int radix)
```

Comment: That (int->String) is the opposite of what OP is trying to do. Did you mean `Integer.parseInt(String str, int radix)`?

Comment: Of course it was parseInt. I have copied wrong method from javadoc. Thank you for comment.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your code is throwing the exception in the else part. Since the String that is being passed is made of white spaces the:

```
if((a.charAt(0)) == '1'){
```

fails and the else takes part. However, since it only try to parseInt it gives the error.

You should first identify why your String is getting in made of white spaces and for this method you could use some kind of protection like throwing an exception right in the beginning if the String is either empty or made of white spaces.

The part that compares the charAt(0) position with 0 is also incorrect as pointed out by other members.

Cheers